# Al compilar mi programa, python no esta corriendo un bucle while aunque la condicion se cierta

Tags: python-3.8

soy un programador novato que esta aprendiendo primeros pasos de Python por mi cuenta y con cursos de youtube. En fin, ire directo al grano:

Como parte de un ejercicio, estoy haciendo un programa que indica cuando una direcccion de correo suministrada por el usuario es valida, asi como tambien pide el correo al usuario, para eso, esoty usando bucles entre esas condiciones es que tenga un arroba (@), luego, que el arroba no este ni al principio ni al final de la direccion suministrada por el usuario, y al final, que sea alguna de las cuentas gmail. hotmail y outlook. El caso es que, cuando yo compilo el programa y yo introduzco un correo sin el @, al parecer python no lee el codigo del primer filtro de validacion(que consiste en un while donde la condicion es que si '@' esta en la variable correo es Falsa, lo cual deberia de leerlo)Yo quiero que el programa me diga error cuando no hay @ el la direccion de correo que suministre el usuario cuando no tiene @. este es el mensaje de error obtenido:

```
==== RESTART: C:\Users\Clarette\Desktop\Python38-32\ejercicios de python.py ====
Por favor, introduzca su direccion de correo electronico: destinychidgmail.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Clarette\Desktop\Python38-32\ejercicios de python.py", line 95, in <module>
    k=validacion(correo)  ##validacion() es una funcion que valida si un correo tiene el arroba al principio o al final. 1 si es asi, 0 si no.
  File "C:\Users\Clarette\Desktop\Python38-32\ejercicios de python.py", line 74, in validacion
    k=correoelectr.index('@')   ##Uso k para reutilizar la variable y asi, optimizar los recursos de la PC. Aqui validamos el indice
ValueError: substring not found
```

Es como si el programa se saltar la instruccion del primer bucle  cuando la variable correo no tiene un arroba, por eso digo que no se porque razon no lee el primer bucle while cuando en esos casos la condicion es Falsa y por ende, deberia ejecutarlo, hay algun problema con la sintaxis? de como evaluar condiciones cuando se maneja con caracteres? Por favor ayudenme a arreglar esto sin modificar tanto el codigo si es posible. De verdad quiero aprender. He aqui el codigo, estoy usando  python 3.8.7 en windows 7.

```
##   Ahora vamos a hacer que un programa te pida una direccion de correo electronico y valide si esa es una direccion de correo valida o no 

def validacion(correoelectr:str):   ##Aqui declararemos una funcion que luego usaremos mas adelante
    n=len(correoelectr)
    k=correoelectr.index('@')   ##Uso k para reutilizar la variable y asi, optimizar los recursos de la PC. Aqui validamos el indice 
    if  k==1 or k==n:
        k=1
    else:
        k=0
    return k



correo=input("Por favor, introduzca su direccion de correo electronico: ")  ##Le pido al usuario su direccion de correo electronico


 
while '@' in correo==False:           ## validacion de si este correo es admisible teniendo un arroba, viendo si la variable 'correo' contiene el caracter @.
    print("Error: Este es un email no valido, debe tener al menos el caracter arroba (@). ")
    correo=input("Por favor, introduzca nuevamente la direccion de correo electronico: ")

##Ahora validaremos si el @ esta al final o al principio. En cualquier caso, no es correo valido:

k=1 ##Para que entre en el bucle a continuacion
while k==1:
  k=validacion(correo)  ##validacion() es una funcion que valida si un correo tiene el arroba al principio o al final. 1 si es asi, 0 si no. 
  if k==1:
      print("Error: El correo no puede contener @ al principio o al final. Correo inadmisible")
      correo=input("Por favor, introduzca nuevamente su direccion de correo electronico: ")  ##vuelvo a pedir correo
  else:    ##Ahora aqui nos aseguraremos que la variable correo contenga "@gmail.com","@hotmail.com" o "@outlook.com"
      
      i=correo.index('@')   ## i es el menor indice donde se encuentra la lista.(usando la variable correo es string. parece que da el mismo resultado que usando S)
      n=len(correo)   ## cantidad de elementos de la lista.
      if correo[i:n]!='@gmail.com' and correo[i:n]!='@hotmail.com' and correo[i:n]!='@outlook.com':
         print("Error: Correo Inadmisible. Solo se registraran los correos que terminan en '@gmail.com','@hotmail.com' o '@outlook.com'")
         correo=input("Por favor, introduzca nuevamente su direccion de correo electronico: ")
      else:
         print("Correo registrado")
         

print("El programa ha finalizado")
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: No es que se salte algo, sino que hay un error por que el método  `index` devuelve la posición del string que buscas pero sí no existe dará error

Comment: Para corregirlo tendrías que hacer una validación antes

Comment: Hola Carlos. ¿Por qué no usas expresiones regulares para validar una direccion del correo?

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que tu código se puede mejorar mucho. Veo que estas aprendiendo, los comienzos son dificiles. Te doy ánimos estoy seguro que con el tiempo mejorarás.

Yo empezaría cambiando esto.

```
correo=input("Por favor, introduzca su direccion de correo electronico: ")
while '@' in correo==False: 
   print("Error: Este es un email no valido, debe tener al menos el caracter arroba (@). ")
   correo=input("Por favor, introduzca nuevamente la direccion de correo electronico: ")
```

Por esto:

```
correo=input("Por favor, introduzca su direccion de correo electronico: ")
if '@' not in correo: 
   print("Error: Este es un email no valido, debe tener al menos el caracter arroba (@). ")
   correo=input("Por favor, introduzca nuevamente la direccion de correo electronico: ")
```

La primera línea comprueba si la variable `correo` contiene al menos una arroba.

Respecto a la **funcion validación**. Independientemente de si tiene sentido o no. Me voy a centrar en mejorarla un poco. Tu funcion es esta:

```
def validacion(correoelectr:str):
    n=len(correoelectr)
    k=correoelectr.index('@') 
    if  k==1 or k==n:
        k=1
    else:
        k=0
    return k
```

Puedes mejorarla asi:

```
def validacion(correoelectr:str):
    return correoelectr.startswith('@') or correoelectr.endswith('@')
```

Simplemente la funcion devuelve True si la validación es correcta. En este punto, te diria que si quieres validar un correo electronico, uses expresiones regulares. Por ejemplo yo he encontrado esto en **gist**:

```
def is_email(email) : 
    regex = re.compile('^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\_])+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\_])+\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})$')

    return regex.match(email)
```

Te animo a buscar mas ejemplos en [gist](https://gist.github.com/search?l=Python&q=validate%20email) y que revises tu código para hacerlo mas sencillo

Comment: Me perdi. Cambiaste un `while` por un `if`, por lo que el programa sólo revisa el primer correo ingresado; el segundo intento es aceptado sin más. ¿Entendi mal?

Comment: Me gustó tu respuesta no sabía del not in, además,  veo que cambiaste el while por el If. Lo que pasa es que a mí me gustaría que el programa siga pidiendo datos cuándo el usuario introduce información errónea.

Answer (score 1):

Un correo bien formado debe componerse por cuenta@dominio.ext, por lo que:

- El mínimo correo valido es `a@b.c`, o >= que 5 caracteres.
- Solo tener caracteres alfanumericos, obligatorio un @ y opcional puntos (.)
- No debe tener dos o más punto seguidos.
- No debe empezar ni terminar por @
- No debe empezar ni terminar por `.`
- Debe haber al menos un punto después de `@`
- No debe haber un punto antes (`xxx.@xxx`) o después (`xxx@.yyy`) del @

Con la información anterior, se podría hacer un validador un poco más ordenado con todas las condiciones y que devuelva True o False si el correo pasa o no.

```
def validacion(correo): 
    largo = len(correo)
    if largo < 5: # El correo más corto que a@b.c (5 caracteres)
        return False
    test = correo.replace('.', '').replace('@', '', 1)
    if not test.isalnum():
        # Si existe un caracter no alfanumerico o más de una @
        return False
    if correo.find('..') >= 0: # Si encuentra dos o más puntos seguidos
        return False
    at_pos = correo.find('@') # Posición de la @
    lpoint = correo.find('.') # Posición del punto mas a la izquierda
    rpoint = correo.rfind('.') # Posición del punto mas a la derecha
    if at_pos in [-1, 0, largo]: # abc.com, @abc.com, abc.com@
        # Si no hay ninguna @, o si @ está al principio o al final
        return False
    elif lpoint == 0 or rpoint+1 == largo:
        # Si empieza o termina con punto: .abc@d.com, acb@d.com.
        return False
    elif rpoint < at_pos:
        # Si no hay ningun punto después de @: abc.d@com
        return False
    elif '.' in [correo[at_pos-1], correo[at_pos+1]]:
        # Si hay un punto antes o despues de @: abc.@d.com, abc@.d.com
        return False
    # Si no se cumplieron ninguna de las condiciones arriba, es valido:
    return True
```

Generalmente lo anterior se hace con regex, pero no impide que se pueda hacer manualmente. Haciendo algunas pruebas:

```
print(validacion('correo@dominio')) # False (falta punto despues de @)
print(validacion('correo@dominio.com')) # True
print(validacion('correo123@dominio.com')) # True
print(validacion('correo123@dominio.com.')) # False (termina en punto)
print(validacion('nombre.apellido@dominio.com')) # True
print(validacion('nombre..apellido@dominio.com')) # False (dos punto seguidos)
print(validacion('correo@dominio@dominio.com')) # False (doble arroba)
print(validacion('correo.@dominio.com')) # False (Punto antes de @)
print(validacion('correo.facultad@universidad.edu.pa')) # True
```